# VBA Excel string datatype variable assignment

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set a value for CurrentClient Variable i have defined below and then using it to count how many times it Occurs in a range. I am not sure what am i doing wrong here . It is giving me error: "runtime error 9 subscript out of range" on step where it is assigning the value from Sheet 2 cell A2 to Currentclient.

Please help.

```
Sub GetValue()

Dim ClientCnt As Integer
Dim CurrentClient As String

CurrentClient = Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A2").Text

ClientCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), CurrentClient)

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `.Text` try `.Value`

Comment: Tried .value also it is giving the same error.

Comment: A2 have a text value which i need to use to set the ClientCnt. I have used variant also instead of String datatype and it is still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Sheet2**

rather than

**Sheet 2**

Comment: *Subscript out of range* is the critical clue!!

Comment: OMG! spent 30 minutes... on this I totttaly missed that. THanks Gary's Student

Comment: @Prat14 _________sometimes error messages **are** useful.

Comment: I am new to VBA programming and getting use to it anyways thanks for this lesson i will keep error messages in mind now.

Comment: @Prat14 I have made this exact error many times myself.  So answering this Post was like greeting an old friend!

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)